# Getting "TypeError: insertstop() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" when there are no arguments in my function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-text

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to put my first application together that takes in trip information and inserts it into a text box for export out to a document.  It's gone pretty good until today when I tried to implement multiple ways of inserting text from an entrybox into a text block with tkinter.

I have an entry widget that inserts text into a text widget when a button is pressed.  That's simple enough but I wanted to make it to where you could simply hit the enter key to do the same thing.

When I implement this function I get the error:

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in __ call __
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: insertstop() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

I've looked the error up and it seems like it would pop up if I put in arguments in my function call but I don't have any arguments in any of my function calls.  Also it seems like maybe this error is related to a class or something?  I haven't learned about classes yet and only have a basic idea of what they are.  Do I need a class to do this?

Coincidentally I also added the argument(self) in my function and that made pressing enter work but it made my insert stop button quit working.

I'm sure I've missed something very basic but I just can't figure out what.

Thanks for any help!

```
import time
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *

# Creates the Tkinter form named "screen"
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("550x645")
screen.title("Test")
# Initialize frames
menuframe = Frame(screen,
                  height=60,width=600,bg="gray",pady=5)
inputframe = Frame(screen,
                   height=300,width=600,pady=5)
outputframe = Frame(screen,
                   height=290,width=600,pady=5)

# Packs the frames so they will display
menuframe.pack()
inputframe.pack()
outputframe.pack()


#==STOPBOX==#

stopbox=Text(inputframe,yscrollcommand=1,height= 10,width=20,
               padx=3,pady=3,relief=GROOVE,bg="gray79")
stopbox.place(x=345, y=90)

def insertstop():
    global stop_vanconv
    stop_vanconv=(stop_entry.get())
    stopbox.insert(END, stop_vanconv + "\n")
    stop_entry.delete("0","end")
    

stoplist_label = Label(inputframe,
                       text="Type stop locations and press" + '\n' +
                       "the Add Stop button to insert a new stop.")
stoplist_label.place(x=100, y=150)

stop_entry = Entry(inputframe,
                      textvariable = " ")
stop_entry.place(x=150, y=190)

addstopbutton = Button(inputframe,text="Add Stop",padx=20,pady=0,
                       activebackground="darkslategray4",command=insertstop)
addstopbutton.place(x=160, y=220)

stop_entry.bind('<Return>',insertstop)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you use `bind`, the function is always called with a parameter that represents the event that triggered the callback. There are several questions on this site about this, and it's covered in the documentation for the `bind` command.

Comment: Is there another way to call a function while an entry box is active?  I thought bind was how you got keyboard actions.

Comment: `bind` _is_ the way to do it. You just have to know how bind works and prepare for it. hint: `def insertstop(event=None)` will make the event parameter optional.

Comment: Thanks dude.  Need to get back to basics but that helps.